# What is the purpose of wierdly named subdirectories for cache directories

Tags: caching, storage, directory

When looking at the "Storage" directory of Spotify's cache I realized there are a lot of subdirectories, named with 2-digit hexadecimal names. Each of them contains one or more weirdly named files.

I've come across similar directory structures created by other programs in the past, and I have always wondered what the reason for such a naming/storing scheme is.

So why would you do such a thing? What benefits does this concept hold?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are still interested in the answer.

Usually you cache things like images or content. Say we cache an image from a different url to our server for performance/stability reasons. How do you name that image? You could name it like the URL, but you cannot include slashes or other special characters in the name and the length has a limit too.

Therefore you compute a so called hash of that URL and use it as the file name. Hashes are usually no hexadecimal, so no illegal characters and their length is always the same. If you now need the image from the URL you compute its hash and check if you find it in the cache.

The reason you dont store all cached files in one directory is for size-limitations. You usually group the cached files in subdirectories based on their first characters. See this answer: [softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/301401](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/301401).

For example let's say we want to cache `https://example.com/favicon.ico`. The MD5-Hash of that URL is `f54403d0da4a57aa79bdf459897f08bd`. You have now three different options:

- If the cache is expected to remain small store it like `/cache/f54403d0da4a57aa79bdf459897f08bd.ico` (You usually want to preserve file-extensions for a number of reasons).
- Four medium caches you could do /cache/f/f54403d0da4a57aa79bdf459897f08bd.ico `or remove duplicate information by trimming the first character, as it already exists in the directory name like /cache/f/54403d0da4a57aa79bdf459897f08bd.ico`
- For very large caches you can subdivide even more like /cache/f/5/4403d0da4a57aa79bdf459897f08bd.ico`

These are just a few examples but the basic principle keeps the same.